# ADSync PowerShell commands failing to authenticate

Tags: powershell, azure-activedirectory

**Environment:** Running Windows Server that has the latest version of **AzureADConnect (2.1.20.0)** installed, all seems to be working just fine though.

**However** when using any of the `ADSync` Powershell commands, such as:

```
Get-ADSyncScheduler
```

**The logs** is reporting this error essentially:

```
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException: AADSTS50126: Error
validating credentials due to invalid username or password.
```

**Questions:**

- Where do ADSync Powershell Cmdlets store their configuration?
- Where's the username / password required to connect to Azure taken from or how I might override it?
- Any other hints or guidances that may help?

**Large exception trace:**

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ADSyncScheduler
Get-ADSyncScheduler : System.InvalidOperationException: There was an issue obtaining cloud sync intervals ---> Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException: AADSTS50126: Error
validating credentials due to invalid username or password.
Trace ID: 58528f5c-6207-495e-9171-be0b61a22c00
Correlation ID: 2bc43dca-124e-46cc-97b2-27b3dd133d3a
Timestamp: 2022-11-18 16:00:14Z
   at Microsoft.Online.Deployment.Client.Framework.MSALAuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateMSAL(AzureService azureService, String userName, SecureString password, Boolean
useCachedToken, String& accessToken, String& errorCode, String& additionalDetails, Boolean throwOnException, Boolean throwExceptionOnMFAError)
   at Microsoft.Online.Deployment.Client.Framework.MSALAuthenticationProvider.AcquireServiceToken(AzureService azureService, String& serviceEndpoint, String& errorCode, String&
additionalDetail, AuthenticationStatus& status, Boolean throwOnException, Boolean throwExceptionOnMFAError)
   at Microsoft.Online.Deployment.Client.Framework.MSALAuthenticationProvider.AcquireServiceToken(AzureService azureService, String& serviceEndpoint, String& additionalDetail,
AuthenticationStatus& status, Boolean throwOnException)
   at Microsoft.Online.Deployment.Client.Framework.MSALAuthenticationProvider.AcquireServiceToken(AzureService azureService, String& additionalDetail, Boolean throwOnException)
   at Microsoft.Online.Coexistence.ProvisionHelper.GetSecurityToken()
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.InitializeProvisionHelper()
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.GetCompanyConfiguration(Boolean includeLicenseInformation)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.AADConfig.get_CloudEnforcedSyncSchedulerInterval()
   at Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.Scheduler.SchedulerSettingUtilities.get_CurrentSchedulerSettings()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.Scheduler.SchedulerSettingUtilities.get_CurrentSchedulerSettings()
   at SchedulerUtils.GetCurrentSchedulerSettings(SchedulerUtils* , _ConfigAttrNode* pcanList, UInt32 ccanItems, Char** syncSettingsSerialized, Char** errorString)
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADSyncScheduler
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (Microsoft.Ident...ADSyncScheduler:GetADSyncScheduler) [Get-ADSyncScheduler], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException: There was an issue obtaining cloud sync intervals ---> Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException: AADSTS50126
   : Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password.
Trace ID: 58528f5c-6207-495e-9171-be0b61a22c00
Correlation ID: 2bc43dca-124e-46cc-97b2-27b3dd133d3a
Timestamp: 2022-11-18 16:00:14Z
       at Microsoft.Online.Deployment.Client.Framework.MSALAuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateMSAL(AzureService azureService, String userName, SecureString password, Boolean useCach
   edToken, String& accessToken, String& errorCode, String& additionalDetails, Boolean throwOnException, Boolean throwExceptionOnMFAError)
       at Microsoft.Online.Deployment.Client.Framework.MSALAuthenticationProvider.AcquireServiceToken(AzureService azureService, String& serviceEndpoint, String& errorCode, String&
   additionalDetail, AuthenticationStatus& status, Boolean throwOnException, Boolean throwExceptionOnMFAError)
       at Microsoft.Online.Deployment.Client.Framework.MSALAuthenticationProvider.AcquireServiceToken(AzureService azureService, String& serviceEndpoint, String& additionalDetail, A
   uthenticationStatus& status, Boolean throwOnException)
       at Microsoft.Online.Deployment.Client.Framework.MSALAuthenticationProvider.AcquireServiceToken(AzureService azureService, String& additionalDetail, Boolean throwOnException)

   at Microsoft.Online.Coexistence.ProvisionHelper.GetSecurityToken()
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.InitializeProvisionHelper()
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.GetCompanyConfiguration(Boolean includeLicenseInformation)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.AADConfig.get_CloudEnforcedSyncSchedulerInterval()
   at Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.Scheduler.SchedulerSettingUtilities.get_CurrentSchedulerSettings()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.Scheduler.SchedulerSettingUtilities.get_CurrentSchedulerSettings()
       at SchedulerUtils.GetCurrentSchedulerSettings(SchedulerUtils* , _ConfigAttrNode* pcanList, UInt32 ccanItems, Char** syncSettingsSerialized, Char** errorString),Microsoft.Iden
   tityManagement.PowerShell.Cmdlet.GetADSyncScheduler
```

Answer (score 0):

#### I wonder where the username / password required to connect to Azure is taken from or how I might override it?

You can set the credentials with `Add-ADSyncADDSConnectorAccount`:

> This cmdlet resets the password for the service account and updates it both in Azure AD and in the sync engine.

> ```
> Add-ADSyncADDSConnectorAccount [-Identifier] <Guid> [-EACredential <PSCredential>] [<CommonParameters>]
> ```

or

> ```
> Add-ADSyncADDSConnectorAccount [-Name] <String> [-EACredential <PSCredential>] [<CommonParameters>]
> ```

Example:

> ```
> Add-ADSyncADDSConnectorAccount -Name contoso.com -EACredential $EAcredentials
> ```

Source: [Azure AD Connect: ADSync PowerShell Reference - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/reference-connect-adsync)

See Also:

- [Azure AD Connect sync service features and configuration - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-syncservice-features)
- [Azure AD Connect: Pass-through Authentication - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-pta)

Answer (score 0):

## Configure Azure AD Connect Server Service Tips

The authentication credential PowerShell uses with those commands are all stored in the **Azure AD Connect** server configurations ***post each configuration you run***. Typically you don't have to be concerned with this much other than saving an export per each change as a backup and securely storing those credentials for future reference if needed.

*Rerunning through the Azure AD Connect configuration wizard again* and typing in appropriate credentials accordingly should get the authentication issues back in sync. You should be able to translate all these steps to PowerShell as well emulating the options you select through the UI.

> **To resolve this issue:**
>
> 1. Log onto the Azure AD Connect server
> 2. Launch **Azure AD Connect**
>
>    [image]
> 3. Select **Configure**
>
>    [image]
> 4. Step through the configuration wizard and configure for your environment accordingly. See [Azure AD sign-in
>    configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-install-custom#azure-ad-sign-in-configuration)
>    for more technical detail and configuration guidance specifics.

### Requirements

- Enter in an Azure AD [Global
  Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#global-administrator)
  or  [Hybrid Identity
  Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#hybrid-identity-administrator) credential when prompted.

  [image]
- Enter an on-premise Domain Administrator credential if you use single
  sign-on when prompted with the configuration wizard.

  [image]

> **Other Advice:**
>
> - The Global Administrator (or Hybrid Identity Administrator) account **must be enabled**
> - The Global Administrator (or Hybrid Identity Administrator) account **must not be expired**
>
>   - Set password for this account to never expire
>   - Set the password for this account extra long and extra complex
> - The Global Administrator (or Hybrid Identity Administrator) account **must not require MFA** to connect to Azure AD
>
>   - Configure policies accordingly to make exceptions

### PowerShell

*Example set password to never expire*

```
Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId x9xxx999-999-9x99-999x-x9xxx99x99xx -PasswordPolicies DisablePasswordExpiration;
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Set-AzureADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0)

  - [`-ObjectId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0#-objectid)

    > Specifies the ID of a user (as a `UPN` or `ObjectId`) in Azure AD
  - [`-AccountEnabled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0#-accountenabled)

    > Indicates whether the account is enabled.
    >
    > **Type:** `Boolean`

Comment: Check your AD Connect server's **Synchronization Service Manager** and confirm there are indeed no issues. The error indicates there is an authentication issue, so rerunning the configuration per the basic way stated above (or translated to PowerShell) should get it back in sync. If accounts expired, etc. you will run into those issues. Happy to help you further troubleshoot if you want to chat back some comments/input/feedback based on my latest edit to more accurately clarify those specifics I stated.

Comment: Also, make sure the AD Connect Sync account with Global admin or Hybrid identity admin is cloud only and not AD sync or created on-premise. In the case I can confirm at the moment, it's GA and is not an onprem AD account nor sync'd between the two. Just use it with onprem AD Connect server to authenticate per that prompt and thus `@yourdomaincom.onmicrosoft.com` UPN. I haven't tested with hybrid identity admin role specifically though. But something to keep in mind for troubleshooting, just create new AAD only account with necessary roles, and try with it. Then run the PS commands afterwards.